# Possible to send two seperate data within the same connection for Twisted TCP?

Tags: android, python, tcp, twisted

I am trying to work on a system where Server will set up a connection and send multiple data in real time to the Client.

In order to simulate "realtime", my server will send 2 data one after another with a delay of 1 sec

```
class IphoneChat(Protocol):
  def connectionMade(self):
    print "a client connected"
    self.transport.setTcpNoDelay(True)
    msg = 'F#m'
    b = msg.encode('utf-8')
    msg2 = 'C'
    c = msg2.encode('utf-8')
    self.transport.write(b)
    time.sleep(1)
    self.transport.write(c)
```

My Android Client will basically recieve each data and print them immediately one after another

```
while(i<2){
                    Log.d("waiting", "waiting");
                    bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer);
                    byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    response = byteArrayOutputStream.toString("UTF-8");
                    i++;
                    Log.d("response", response);

                    //immediately run UIthread
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            textResponse.setText(response);
                        }
                    });

                }
```

However, it seem like the client is taking both F#m and C at the same time and display them together as "F#mC" instead of "F#m" then "C".

Is that because TCP is unable to do what I mentioned and I have to use UDP to do it?

Comment: Don't use `time.sleep` in a Twisted program.  The way to delay an action in a Twisted program is `reactor.callLater`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, yes, that's because TCP is unable to do what you've mentioned. TCP is a stream of bytes, not a stream of messages. As far as TCP is concerned, you've sent the bytes `F`, `#`, `m`, and `C`, and whether the client reads them as 3 bytes followed by 1 byte, 4 bytes all at once, or 2 bytes followed by 2 bytes is completely arbitrary.*

But that doesn't mean you have to use UDP. If you want to send separate messages over TCP, you just have to come up with some way to separate the messages yourself—a length prefix, a terminator or separator, a self-delineating format for the messages, etc.

In Twisted, you usually do this in the `Protocol` class; in fact, that's pretty much the point of protocols.

See [Sockets are byte streams, not message streams](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/sockets-are-byte-streams-not-message.html) for some general (non-Twisted) examples of building simple protocols on top of TCP. But one dead simple (and easy to human-debug!) one, which works if your messages are plain text with no possible newlines in them, is just to send each message on a separate line, the same way you would if writing messages to a file:

```
b = (msg + '\n').encode('utf-8')
```

The client side will need to buffer up the bytes it receives, storing them until it sees one or more `\n` characters, then split and process each complete line as a message, and remember the final incomplete line and continue the buffering from there. Python/Twisted has a lot of tools to make this part easy; I don't know about Android. But you can always do it manually, something like this (untested quasi-Java pseudocode):

```
ByteArray buf = new ByteArray();
while(i<2){
    Log.d("waiting", "waiting");
    bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer);
    buf.append(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    Array<ByteArray> lines = buf.split('\n');
    buf = lines.popLast();
    for (ByteArray line in lines) {
        byteArrayOutputStream.write(line, 0, line.length());
        response = byteArrayOutputStream.toString("UTF-8");
        i++;
        Log.d("response", response);

        //immediately run UIthread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                textResponse.setText(response);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

<sub>* In practice, because of the way packets and buffers and so forth work, you will sometimes see the reads exactly match the writes—especially when testing on localhost, on an unloaded machine, with long gaps between the writes, etc. But you can't rely on that in real conditions.</sub>

Comment: Abarnert, thanks for your advice. Can I clarify, your code seem to suggest that it takes in what is read and using a \n to separate the msg from the read buffer. However, does it solve the issue of reading it in real time in the sense example: 'C\n' is send, 5 secs later 'D\n' is sent. Does the client waits for 5 sec for both C and D to be send then performs the above seperation or once it recieves C\n, it is able to immediately extract that out and at the mean time wait for the next one(which is D)? And the latter is what I would like to achieve

Comment: @LimGangyi: The client won't wait 5 seconds. Whenever it gets at least `'C\n'`—which should be right away—it'll process the `'C'`. But of course it's always possible that, what with packet loss and resends and all that, the `'C\n'` won't arrive until the `'D\n'` (or just the `'D'`) have already arrived. This just guarantees that it'll still process the `'C'` and the `'D'` as separate messages.

Comment: @LimGangyi: If you want more-real-time-ish behavior, at the cost of higher overhead, you can turn off the `TCP_NODELAY` socket option. See [Wikipedia's article on the Nagle algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle's_algorithm) to understand this. But don't do that until you have the basic protocol working.

Comment: Cool, thats great news! Can I just ask one more question, as I am really new to Java, I cant seem to find ByteArray, I believe it is byte[] yup? if thats the case, what does Array<ByteArray> means?

Comment: @LimGangyi: I'm really rusty with Java, so I can't help you too much there, but `byte[]` seems reasonable. And `Array<ByteArray>` is meant to be… well, assuming Java has a bytearray-splitting method similar to Python's `bytearray.split`, it's whatever type that returns, akin to Python's `list` of `bytearray`s. I guess `Array<ByteArray>` because a generic array whose members are byte arrays seemed about right.

Comment: I have manage to implement the code, however it doesnt seem to be working how I wanted. the server sends as such wait 5 sec, send 1st data, wait 5 sec, sends 2nd data.
But on the reciever side, it prints as such. wait 10secs, print 1st data, print 2nd data.
Have have updated the code below for better clarification. Appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 0):

I have actually made amendments to the code base on the advice from @abarnert.

My Client is now able to print out the Characters separately. However the problem is that instead of printing out in real time, it is waiting until all the data is sent before it prints out the results sequentially but in ms difference.

My server actually sends 2 data out after every 5 secs as such:
Once connection starts, wait 5 sec, send 1st data, wait 5 secs, send 2nd data.
However, on my android Client side, it waited for 10secs before printing out both data sequentially.

Am I doing something wrong here such that it is unable to print them in real time?

Regards,

\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
Updated Server Code
\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

```
class IphoneChat(Protocol):
def connectionMade(self):
    print "a client connected"
    self.transport.setTcpNoDelay(True)

    int = 0

    while(True):
        time.sleep(5)
        msg = 'F#m'
        b = (msg + '/').encode('utf-8')
        msg2 = 'C'
        c = (msg2 + '/').encode('utf-8')

        if int==0:
            self.transport.write(b)
            int = 1
        else:
            self.transport.write(c)
            int = 0
            break
```

\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
Updated Client Code
\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

```
            socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);

            Log.d("socket created", "socket created");

            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(
                    1024);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1];

            int bytesRead;
            InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();

            /*
             * notice: inputStream.read() will block if no data return
             */
            //while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {

            while(true){
                Log.d("waiting", "waiting");
                while(!byteArrayOutputStream.toString().contains("/")){
                    bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer);
                    byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    Log.d("buffer", buffer.toString());
                }

                //byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                response = byteArrayOutputStream.toString("UTF-8");
                response = response.substring(0, response.length()-1);
                byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(
                        1024);

                Log.d("response", response);



                //immediately run UIthread
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Log.d("printing", "printing");
                        textResponse.setText(response);
                    }
                });

            }
```

Comment: This is really a new question, and should be asked as such (either by creating a new question if your original one was solved, or by editing this one if it wasn't). But first… have you tried disabling nagling, as I explained in a comment on my answer, or read the Wikipedia article explaining it?